# Send data from ViewModel to ViewModel and showing on ViewPages

Tags: android, shell, xamarin.forms, mvvm, data-binding

I have two Views, Coffee and Doppio coffee (maybe any coffee). CoffeeView is a list of available coffees, and when one Coffee has taped, it will open its details page (in this example, Doppio has tapped).
I have two ViewModels, CoffeViewModel and CoffeeDetailsViewModel, respectively.

I can implement this scenario but can't MVVMify it. I know about routing. I can pass variables on routing but not between ViewModels. See the below Picture. When I tap on a specific item on Coffee, I want it to send its data from CoffeeViewModel to its CoffeeDetailsViewModel and at the same time open its DetailsViewPage and show data on that page.

[image: Two View Pages and Two ViewModels]

```
 await Navigation.PushAsync(new CoffeeDetailsPage(family));
```

or

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(CoffeeDetialsPage)}?Data={Data}");
```

I have used the above routing syntax, but it can post data to CoffeeDetails.XAML.cs not to its ViewModel, and when I want to send data to its ViewModel, it doesn't launch its page.

**Update**

The ViewModels are instantiated in Xaml using the below syntax.

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModel:CoffeeViewModel></ViewModel:CoffeeViewModel>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Comment: `CoffeeDetailsPage` should use the parameter to create it's VM.  Or there are other MVVM frameworks that support navigation directly between VM's.

Comment: @Jason Can you explain how to use the parameter for creating ViewModel?

Comment: in your first example you pass `family` to `CoffeeDetailsPage`, so when `CoffeeDetailsPage` creates it's VM it can just pass `family` via the VM constructor.  That's a fairly typical pattern to use

Comment: @Jason but this passes the `family` variable to `CoffeDetailsPage.Xaml.cs` not to its `ViewModel`.

Comment: where is the VM created for that page?

Comment: @Jason Coffee and CoffeeDetails pages are in the Views folder, and CoffeeViewModel and CoffeeDetailsViewModel are in the ViewModel folder.

Comment: That is not what I asked.  Where is the VM for the page instantiated?

Comment: @Jason see I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you assign the VM in the constructor you can easily pass a parameter to it

```
public CoffeeDetailsPage(Family family)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = new CoffeeViewModel(family);
}
```

Comment: There is another problem with this solution. 
The CoffeeViewModel downloads data from Firebase based on the family variable passed to this ViewModel, and I used asynchronous methods there. 
The problem is with `InitializeComponent();` because this executes before loading the data and throws the exception. `Object reference not set to an instance of an object...`

Comment: `InitializeComponent` just initializes the XAML.  It shouldn't be dependent on anything else.  You need to figure out the root cause of the exception and solve it - don't just make assumptions about what causes it